# Converting the column format numbers from 12345 to 12,345 (1234567 to 1,234,567) in Gridview when typing

Tags: c#, winforms

I was able to change the gridview value to my own format by defining the textbox and getting the cell value from the gridview and solved the problem.
Another problem has arisen. The operation of addition from the total amount column is not performed. Because there is a comma in the values. I tried to remove them using Replace(",","") but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you referring to [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control in WinForms or a [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control in WebForms?

Comment: It appears you're mixing the `Value` of a Cell with its `FormattedValue`. The Cell's Type should be `int` (or any other Type that fits), not `string`, while the `Format` should be, based what you're showing, `"N0"`. When you operate on the Cells, you handle the `Value` (which has no format, it's just a *number*) -- Not clear what *defining the textbox* means.

Comment: How are you populating your DataGridView? What is your DataSource?

Comment: For Reza: DataGridView in winForm.

Comment: For Jimi: Value for own cell is string.

Comment: For Rodrigues: Without data source. Dgv for invoice app. I type 12345, and afted cellEndEdit, calculate. I want type 12345 and show 12,345 in own cell.

Comment: You are creating your own problems. First you “should” use a `DataSource` for the grid with a `DataTable` or `List<T>`. In the data source, you could define a column/property as an `int` type… THEN, you can easily set that grid column’s `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property to anything you want and dump your unnecessary current code that is manually formatting the text. Going down the path you are is only going to create more work and problems for you which can be noted by you having to “remove” the commas in the numbers. None of that should be necessary.